# DynamoDB and Laravel, Why I cant send data to my DDBB from a controller?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-dynamodb

I have lost 40 minutes looking for an asnwer to this problem. =(

I have this Route in my routes.php:

```
Route:post('prueba', function(){
if(Request::ajax()){
   $data = Input::all();

    $purchase = new Purchase();
    $purchase->buyer_id = '44444499999';
    $purchase->payment_type = 'ewiicfifif';

    $purchase->save();

   return $data; 
}
});
```

If I execute this route, everything is ok, and I can set the values in my DDBB in DynamoDB:

But, I don´t want the code in the route php, then, I have this:

```
Route::post('prueba', 'PruebaController@pruebaMet');
```

Ok, then, I have my controller:

```
use Auction\Purchase;

public function pruebaMet(){
 if(Request::ajax()){
       $data = Input::all();

        $purchase = new Purchase();
        $purchase->buyer_id = '12345';
        $purchase->payment_type = 'Javi';

        $purchase->save();

       return $data; 
    } 
}
```

But if I execute this route, I get nothing in my DDBB, I was thinking "maybe is the route", them, I changed all the code in my function pruebaMet() and I just put this "return "hello word", them, I can get data in my html. without problem.

Someone can help me?  Why I can´t get the info in my database?

```
<?php

namespace Auction\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auction\Http\Requests;
use Auction\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Input; 

use Auction\Purchase;

class PruebaController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('prueba');
}


public function pruebaMet(){
  if(Request::ajax()){
       $data = Input::all();

        $purchase = new Purchase();
        $purchase->buyer_id = '12345';
        $purchase->payment_type = 'Javi';

        $purchase->save();

       return $data; 
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your full controller ?